# Calculating the directional derivative without finding an explicit curve on the surface

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, surfaces

If we have a surface, say $S$, and a smooth map $f: S \to R$ (or $\mathbb{R}^3$), and a parametrization of that surface $ x: U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to S$, how do we find the directional derivative of $f$ along a tangent vector $v$ at $p \in x(U)$ ?

Almost all the books defines the directional derivative of such a map as the derivative of $f\circ c$ where $c$ is a curve on $S$ passing through $p$ with derivative $v$ at $p$; however, finding such a curve, I think, is not practical, in general.Therefore, I would like to calculate $\nabla_v f$ with the help of the parametrisation $x$.

Comment: Huh?  Work out which vector $w\in T_{x^{-1}p}U$ the tangent vector $v$ corresponds to and let $c(t):=x(x^{-1}p+tw)$.

Comment: @user10354138 What if we are trying to calculate it for any arbitrary $v$ ? In general, figuring out $w$ doesn't seem to be that much easy.

Comment: $\hat f = f\circ x$ is a map from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^n$, with derivative $D\hat f$. As a tangent vector, $v = a_1 \partial_{x_1} + a_2 \partial_{x_2}$. Then the directional derivative of $f$ in direction $v$ is $$D\hat f\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair But a tangent vector for a surface has 3 component, i.e it lives in $R^3$ even though it is restricted to a 2 dim. subspace, we cannot multiply $Df$ with that vector, since the matrxi has 2 column, whereas the vector has 3 rows.

Comment: @onurcanbektas A tangent vector to a surface lives in the tangent space of the surface. What you are thinking is a surface embedded in a 3-dimensional manifold, for example embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas If $S$ is an abstract surface, then $v$ is an equivalence class of curves in $S$. If $S$ is an embedded surface, and $v$ is given as a vector in the tangent space of the ambient space, then you first need to compute one curve on $S$ that represents that tangent vector on $S$. Computing a pull back along $x$ is an equivalent work.

Comment: I didn't apply $D\hat f$ to a 3D vector. $a_1, a_2$ are scalars that I've placed in a 2d column vector. If you want to consider the tangent space to be a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ (which natively,it is not - the identification is only by an embedding), that is your perogative. But that makes $\partial_{x_1}, \partial_{x_2}$ 3D vectors, not $\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}$. Since $\hat f$ (note the hat) is from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^n, D\hat f$ is a $n\times 2$ matrix.